# Read multipule Raster in R

Tags: r, raster

I am trying to read multiple raster files in r I used two methods:
**1** `allrasters1 <- lapply(rastlist, raster)`
**2**  `allrasters2 <- stack(rastlist)`

in the both cases I got the same error [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIJjX.jpg)

[image]

I tried the following solutions:
**1** update the packages
**2** re-install r (latest version)
but none of them work !!

here is the full code:

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
rastlist <- list.files(path = "D:\\Learn\\R\\Clip\\rasters", pattern='.tif', 
                       all.files=TRUE, full.names=FALSE)
allrasters1 <- lapply(rastlist, raster)

allrasters2 <- stack(rastlist)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you set `full.names=FALSE`? That seems like the problem. Since you are looking in a different directly you'll need the full path so `full.names=TRUE` would make more sense.

Comment: Thank you. this was the main problem